# Still getting memory error in R when doing a database query. Added joins to my code, but they did not stop the error

Tags: r

Using the nycflights13 library in R to do a database query.  Was getting a memory error because the vector size was too large.  I added some joins to make the query more specific and they reduced the vector size, but I am still getting the memory error.  I have done all the joins I can do from the flights and weather tables. My ultimate goal is to generate a list of all the flights that departed from Newark Airport with less than a 10-minute delay and when the temperature was less than 40 degrees.  Please help! My code is below:

```
weather_text<-"SELECT f.origin, f.flight, f.dep_delay, f.year, f.month,f.day,f.hour,w.temp
              FROM weather w 
              JOIN flights f 
              ON f.origin=w.origin
              AND f.year=w.year
              AND f.month=w.month
              AND f.day=w.day
              AND f.hour=w.hour
              WHERE f.dep_delay<10 AND w.temp<40"

weather_req<-dbSendQuery(con,weather_text)

weather_df<-dbFetch(weather_req)

dbClearResult(weather_req)

head(weather_df)
```

Comment: Can you check how many rows you are returning from the database? Wrap your whole sql as shown in `select count(*) from (...)` to make sure you are selecting what you expect? Or try a really small selection first to make sure the setup works in general?

Comment: Works fine for me (54,209 records returned). But you're hiding some steps, so maybe show all your code.

Comment: Thanks!  I did a select for each dataframe separately, then left-joined them later.

Comment: @Edward, I did not hide any code.  This was everything!  Not sure what else I could do.

Comment: Isn't the standard "join" an inner join, not a left join?

Comment: Where's the code to create `con`?

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail!  Your suggestion worked perfectly!